# iscsiadm is not able to login in any port except 3260

Tags: linux, networking, iscsi

Discovery is successful:

[root@ncdqd0110 iqn.11351.com.xxx:AAA]# iscsiadm -m discoverydb -t sendtargets -p 127.0.0.1:54541 --discover

127.0.0.1:54541,-1 iqn.2495.com.xxx:AAA

Login is failing:

[root@ncdqd0110 ~]# iscsiadm --mode node --target iqn.2495.com.xxx:AAA --portal 127.0.0.1:54541 --login

Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2495.com.xxx:AAA, portal: 127.0.0.1,54541] (multiple)

iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2495.com.xxx:AAA, portal: 127.0.0.1,54541].

iscsiadm: initiator reported error (8 - connection timed out)

iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals

This is happening in Redhat v7.0. In Suse its working fine.

Few results of commands are given below:

[root@ncdqd0110 iqn.2495.com.xxx:AAA]# netstat -rn

Kernel IP routing table

Destination Gateway Genmask Flags MSS Window irtt Iface

0.0.0.0 10.31.224.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eno16780032

10.31.224.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.252.0 U 0 0 0 eno16780032

[root@ncdqd0110 ~]# ip route show

default via 10.31.224.1 dev eno16780032 proto static metric 1024

10.31.224.0/22 dev eno16780032 proto kernel scope link src 10.31.227.110

BEGIN RECORD 6.2.0.873-21
node.name = iqn.2495.com.xxx:AAA

node.tpgt = -1

node.startup = automatic

node.leading_login = No

iface.net_ifacename = eno16780032

iface.iscsi_ifacename = default

iface.transport_name = tcp

iface.vlan_id = 0

iface.vlan_priority = 0

iface.iface_num = 0

iface.mtu = 0

iface.port = 0

iface.tos = 0

iface.ttl = 0

iface.tcp_wsf = 0

iface.tcp_timer_scale = 0

iface.def_task_mgmt_timeout = 0

iface.erl = 0

iface.max_receive_data_len = 0

iface.first_burst_len = 0

iface.max_outstanding_r2t = 0

iface.max_burst_len = 0

node.discovery_address = 127.0.0.1

node.discovery_port = 54541

node.discovery_type = send_targets

node.session.initial_cmdsn = 0

node.session.initial_login_retry_max = 8

node.session.xmit_thread_priority = -20

node.session.cmds_max = 128

node.session.queue_depth = 32

node.session.nr_sessions = 1

node.session.auth.authmethod = None

node.session.timeo.replacement_timeout = 120

node.session.err_timeo.abort_timeout = 15

node.session.err_timeo.lu_reset_timeout = 30

node.session.err_timeo.tgt_reset_timeout = 30

node.session.err_timeo.host_reset_timeout = 60

node.session.iscsi.FastAbort = Yes

node.session.iscsi.InitialR2T = No

node.session.iscsi.ImmediateData = Yes

node.session.iscsi.FirstBurstLength = 262144

node.session.iscsi.MaxBurstLength = 16776192

node.session.iscsi.DefaultTime2Retain = 0

node.session.iscsi.DefaultTime2Wait = 2

node.session.iscsi.MaxConnections = 1

node.session.iscsi.MaxOutstandingR2T = 1

node.session.iscsi.ERL = 0

node.conn[0].address = 127.0.0.1

node.conn[0].port = 54541

node.conn[0].startup = manual

node.conn[0].tcp.window_size = 524288

node.conn[0].tcp.type_of_service = 0

node.conn[0].timeo.logout_timeout = 15

node.conn[0].timeo.login_timeout = 15

node.conn[0].timeo.auth_timeout = 45

node.conn[0].timeo.noop_out_interval = 5

node.conn[0].timeo.noop_out_timeout = 5

node.conn[0].iscsi.MaxXmitDataSegmentLength = 0

node.conn[0].iscsi.MaxRecvDataSegmentLength = 262144

node.conn[0].iscsi.HeaderDigest = None

node.conn[0].iscsi.IFMarker = No

node.conn[0].iscsi.OFMarker = No

END RECORD
If any one know regarding this issue please let me know, how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an SELinux policy choice. The discovery session is running within iscsiadm, but iscsid is restricted in which ports it can connect to.

One option is to use the audit2why/audit2allow utils from policycoreutils to create a local policy module, extending the default system SELinux policy to allow this.